# Trouble initializing a JavaScript module

Tags: javascript, ckan

Just trying and testing CKAN going through the documentation. So far so good but I'm having trouble initializing a JavaScript module.

I followed these steps, http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/javascript.html#initializing-a-javascript-module, restarted the server, loaded the page and the button is there, I can see the newly created JS file in the page but it's not being initialized so no output in the console.

If I add another console.log anywhere not inside `initialize: function () {}` in the JS file it gets outputted.

Maybe some other steps missing here? Do I need to register the CKAN module somewhere?

Comment: Did you add the `data-module="example_theme_popover"` attribute to the button?

Comment: @amercader Yes I did.

Comment: @RiccardoErra check if you are importing js in your template e.g {% resource 'path-to-scipt/script.js' %}

Comment: Finally managed to find a solution for this. I think CKAN doesn't maintain very well versions/releases and documentations in sync. Even if the latest stable release is 2.6.2, the latest version of the docs is referring to a future version.
You can see here the differences between 2.6.2 docs, http://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.6.2/theming/javascript.html , and latest docs, http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/javascript.html .

Comment: any chance you remember what the solution was?

Comment: @user3366016 If I remember correctly using the doc for the latest version solved the issue for me: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/theming/javascript.html#initializing-a-javascript-module. Anything specific not working for you?